# Hide master page quick launch from sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-part

I need to hide quick launch in certain subsites in sp 2013.
Below is the sample code (ascx.cs) i Tried, but quick launch is still visible.
Not sure what is wrong with the code below.

```
 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        try
        {
            if (render != "0")
            {
          if (IsSubSite()) 
                    {
                        HideLeftNav();
     }
    }
   }

    private void HideStandardLeftNavForSite()
    {
        //ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_QuickLaunchNavigationManager
        Control StandardLeftNavCtrl = FindControl(Page.Master.Controls, "QuickLaunchNavigationManager");
        if (StandardLeftNavCtrl != null)
            StandardLeftNavCtrl.Visible = false;
    }

    private void HideLeftNav()
    {
        Panel StandardLeftNavCtrl = (Panel)FindControl(Page.Master.Controls, "pnlQuickLaunch");
        if (StandardLeftNavCtrl != null)
            StandardLeftNavCtrl.Visible = false;           

    }
```

Thanks
Venky

Comment: Will javascript and css help your case ?

Answer (score 0):

First create a css file and add below inside that

```
 <style type="text/css">  
      #sideNavBox {    
           display:none;  
      }  
 </style>
```

Now your code behind will be

```
if (IsSubSite()) {
    HtmlLink styleLink = new HtmlLink();
    styleLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    styleLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css"); 
    styleLink.Href = "http://cssurl"; 
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(styleLink);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it is not working.


'protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
                CssRegistration.Register("/_layouts/15/1033/styles/hidequicklaunch.css");
        }'

Comment: Can you view page source and check the style is getting registered.. Also debug and make sure it goes inside the if condition

Comment: I can see that in view source and link is fine. It works, if i put that same block of css in an existing static css file referenced in master page. So the style works, But not through code. Does it has to be registered prerender or page init?

Comment: Try moving the code in Pre Render events

Comment: View source:
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/hidequicklaunch.css"/>
<div class="left-navContainer ms-dialogHidden">
    <div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
           <div id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" class="ms-core-navigation" role="navigation">


       
       <div class="ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin">
       
                             **  <div id= "quickLaunch">**
            <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_QuickLaunchNavigationManager" class="ms-Dialoghidden">

Comment: css link is correct and it has
<style type="text/css">  
      #quickLaunch {    
           display:none !important;  
      }  
 </style>

Not sure why the contents inside "quicklaunch" div is not hidden,